# How can I view the final appSettings values on an Azure App Service web app?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I have an ASP.NET MVC app deployed to Microsoft Azure App Service and am having some trouble with the appSettings and connectionStrings values.

I have some values set in the web.config and some values overriding them in the Application Settings tab of the App Service. I want to quickly and easily view the **final** values to check that the settings are being picked up correctly.

How can I do this?

Note: I've tried using `az webapp config appsettings list` but this only seems to bring back what is configured in the Application Settings of the App Service and not the merged results of combining with web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Azure API will return values that include settings that come from your web.config file.

The only way to get this is to ask the config system within your own runtime. e.g. Use code along these lines:

```
foreach (string name in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
{
  string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name];
  ...
}

foreach (ConnectionStringSettings settings in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
  string connStr = settings.ConnectionString;
  string provider = settings.ProviderName;
  ...
}
```

This will give you the effective values that are applied to your app.

Comment: Ok, that's unfortunate. I was hoping that there might be away to view the values without modifying the app.

Comment: Yep, I understand what you were after, but there really is no way. Nothing looks at your web.config until you're app starts running.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the following blades in Azure Portal (under Development Tools section):

[image]

### Console

In order to see the file, you may use [`type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) command, e.g.:

```
type web.config
```

### Advanced Tools

This points to the [Kudu service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu).

You may see files deployed when navigating to Debug Console > Choose either CMD or PowerShell. Then navigate to your config directory (e.g. site/wwwroot) and choose to either download or edit file.

[image]

### App Service Editor

App Service Editor is a relatively new tool in Azure toolset. Default view is a list of files, so you can browse all hosted files, including configuration ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these are actually accurate, as they do not reflect the configuration settings specified under the App Service configuration in the portal

Answer (score 0):

You can view all of your runtime appSettings, connection strings and environment variables (and more..) using [azure KUDU SCM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/05/15/using-kudu-and-deploying-apps-into-azure/). if your application address is "https://app_name.azurewebsites.net" you can access it in the address "https://app_name**.scm**.azurewebsites.net" or from [azure portal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/)

With [kudo REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API), you can get the settings, delete or post them in this address https://app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings

[kudo wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)